# Deal with a huge table latex with a lot columns

Tags: tables, tabularx, threeparttable

I have a table with 11 columns, this is the code:

```
\documentclass[conference,article, 8pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8}
\newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\rothead}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\tabhead{#1}}}
\newsavebox\mysavebox
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[!t]
      \caption{Results}
      \label{tab:tb1}
      \centering
      \begin{threeparttable}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{l >{\raggedright}p{5em} l l l l l}
          \toprule
          \rothead{Name} & \rothead{Category} &
          \rothead{Size\tnote{1}} & \rothead{Number of vertices} &
          \rothead{Number of edges} & \rothead{std. dev} &
          \rothead{Avg. degree} & \rothead{Avg. diameter} & \rothead{Avg. time 1\tnote{2}} & \rothead{Avg. time 2} & \rothead{Avg. time 3\quad} \\
          \midrule
          I-SB0-SWR0 & --- & 9.670 & 6.383 & 4.587 & 9.896 & --- & --- & --- & --- & ---\\
          II-SB4-SWR0 & 4 Steel Bars \O 6 mm & 15.80 & 9.966 & 5.10
              & 15.451 & 56.133 & --- & --- & --- & --- & ---\\
          III-SB0-SWR4 & 4 P-SWRs \O 3 mm & 14.650 & 9.369 & 5.338
              & 14.525 & 46.776 & --- & --- & --- & --- & ---\\
          IV-SB2-SWR2 & 2 Steel Bars \O 6 mm and 2 P-SWRs \O 3 mm
              & 15.240 & 9.680 & 5.748 & 15.0 & 51.576 & --- & --- & --- & --- & ---\\
          V-SB0-SWR8 & 8 P-SWRs \O 3 mm & 19.490 & 12.050 & 7.720
              & 18.682 & 88.783 & --- & --- & --- & --- & ---\\
          \bottomrule\\
        \end{tabular}}
        \begin{tablenotes}
          \item[1] In MB
          \item[2] In ms
        \end{tablenotes}
      \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table*}
  \end{document}
```

But the table is too big and it can't be fixed in a line for the greater columns. The result is the following:

[image]

How can I fix it to have them in just one line for the all columns (the troubled columns are the last 4)? I also tried with a rotation of 45° for columns names.

Comment: Please make your code fragment compilable (missed are `\begin{document}`, etc) and minimal.

Comment: @Zarko I edited the code, now it works just copy and paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare only only 7 columns, but your table have 11 ...

See if the following gives desired result:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath} loaded by mathtools
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsfonts} loaded by amssymb
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx} & you not need to declare driver pdftex
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8}
\newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\rothead}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\tabhead{#1}}}
\newsavebox\mysavebox

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Results}
    \label{tab:tb1}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                            l >{\raggedright}p{5em} *{9}{l}}
      \toprule
      \rothead{Name} 
        & \rothead{Category} 
            & \rothead{Size\tnote{1}} 
                & \rothead{Number of vertices} 
                    & \rothead{Number of edges} 
                        & \rothead{std. dev} 
                            & \rothead{Avg. degree} 
                                & \rothead{Avg. diameter} 
                                    & \rothead{Avg. time 1\tnote{2}} 
                                        & \rothead{Avg. time 2} 
                                            & \rothead{Avg. time 3} \\
          \midrule
I-SB0-SWR0  & ---   & 9.670 & 6.383 & 4.587  & 9.896  & ---    & --- & --- & --- & ---\\
II-SB4-SWR0 & 4 Steel Bars \O 6 mm 
                    & 15.80 & 9.966 & 5.10   & 15.451 & 56.133 & --- & --- & --- & ---\\
III-SB0-SWR4 & 4 P-SWRs \O 3 mm 
                    & 14.650 & 9.369 & 5.338 & 14.525 & 46.776 & --- & --- & --- & --- \\
IV-SB2-SWR2 & 2 Steel Bars \O 6 mm and 2 P-SWRs \O 3 mm
                    & 15.240 & 9.680 & 5.748 & 15.0   & 51.576 & --- & --- & --- & --- \\
V-SB0-SWR8 & 8 P-SWRs \O 3 mm   
                    & 19.490 & 12.050& 7.720 & 18.682 & 88.783 & --- & --- & --- & --- \\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
        \begin{tablenotes}
          \item[1] In MB
          \item[2] In ms
        \end{tablenotes}
      \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, instead `l` column type I would rather use for numbers `S` column defined in `siunitx` and for column headers `\rothead` as defined in the `makecell` package.

**Edit:**
Considering your comment (that you like to have table 12 columns where the cells in the second column can have multi lines text), and adding in the last table's row dummy numbers to have better filling about columns "density". Showed are two cases:

- second column is still `l` type`
- second column is `p{...}` type as you desired.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Avg. time 3\tnote{2}}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Results}
    \label{tab:tb1}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                            l 
                            l@{\qquad}
                            S[table-format=2.3]@{\qquad}
                            *{9}{S[table-format=2.3]} }
    \toprule
\rothead{Name}
    & {\rothead{Category}}
        & {\rothead{Size\tnote{1}}}
            & {\rothead{Number of vertices}}
                & {\rothead{Number of edges}}
                    & {\rothead{std. dev}}
                        & {\rothead{Avg. degree}}
                            & {\rothead{Avg. diameter}}
                                & {\rothead{Avg. time 1\tnote{2}}}
                                    & {\rothead{Avg. time 2}}
                                        & {\rothead{Avg. time 3}}
                                            & {\rothead{twelfth column}}\\
    \midrule
I-SB0-SWR0   & {---} & 9.670 & 6.383 & 4.587  & 9.896  & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---} \\
II-SB4-SWR0  & 4 Steel Bars \O 6 mm
                     & 15.80 & 9.966 & 5.10   & 15.451 & 56.133 & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---} \\
III-SB0-SWR4 & 4 P-SWRs \O 3 mm
                     & 14.650 & 9.369 & 5.338 & 14.525 & 46.776 & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---} \\
IV-SB2-SWR2  & 2 Steel Bars \O 6 mm and 2 P-SWRs \O 3 mm
                     & 15.240 & 9.680 & 5.748 & 15.0   & 51.576 & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---} \\
V-SB0-SWR8   & 8 P-SWRs \O 3 mm
                     & 19.490 & 12.050& 7.720 & 18.682 & 88.783 & 12.345 & 12.345 & 12.345 & 12.345 & 12.345\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
  \item[1] In MB
  \item[2] In ms
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table*}

   \begin{table*}
    \centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Avg. time 3\tnote{2}}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Results}
    \label{tab:tb2}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                            l
                            >{\raggedright}p{10em}@{\qquad}
                            S[table-format=2.3]@{\qquad}
                            *{9}{S[table-format=2.3]} }
    \toprule
\rothead{Name}
    & {\rothead{Category}}
        & {\rothead{Size\tnote{1}}}
            & {\rothead{Number of vertices}}
                & {\rothead{Number of edges}}
                    & {\rothead{std. dev}}
                        & {\rothead{Avg. degree}}
                            & {\rothead{Avg. diameter}}
                                & {\rothead{Avg. time 1\tnote{2}}}
                                    & {\rothead{Avg. time 2}}
                                        & {\rothead{Avg. time 3}}
                                            & {\rothead{twelfth column}}\\
    \midrule
I-SB0-SWR0   & {---} & 9.670 & 6.383 & 4.587  & 9.896  & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---} \\
II-SB4-SWR0  & 4 Steel Bars \O 6 mm
                     & 15.80 & 9.966 & 5.10   & 15.451 & 56.133 & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---} \\
III-SB0-SWR4 & 4 P-SWRs \O 3 mm
                     & 14.650 & 9.369 & 5.338 & 14.525 & 46.776 & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---} \\
IV-SB2-SWR2  & 2 Steel Bars \O 6 mm and 2 P-SWRs \O 3 mm
                     & 15.240 & 9.680 & 5.748 & 15.0   & 51.576 & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---}  & {---} \\
V-SB0-SWR8   & 8 P-SWRs \O 3 mm
                     & 19.490 & 12.050& 7.720 & 18.682 & 88.783 & 12.345 & 12.345 & 12.345 & 12.345 & 12.345\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
  \item[1] In MB
  \item[2] In ms
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Will, now is added solution where are for numbers used `S` columns.

Comment: The second solution returns me an error; however I want to have more space between specific columns (e.g. for col 2 and 3 and 3 with 4); how can I do that?

Comment: @Will, see edited second example. Is now enough space around third column?

Comment: I have some troubles using the secondo solution. Can you edit the first solution to add space between two specific columns ? Now I have 12 columns so I change after \begin{tabular*} from {\raggedright}p{5em} *{9}{l}} to {\raggedright}p{5em} *{10}{l}}

Comment: @Will, just insert `@{\qquad}` before and after desired column as is done in the second example.  If it gives to small space, replace `\quad` with `\hspace{<width>}`, where the `<width>` is desired distance between columns.

Comment: @Will, see edited answer.

Comment: thanks it works using the \hspace. Instead if I would to reduce the space between two columns ?

Comment: I solved using negative values. The problem is that when I increase the space the name of the column also moves to the right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110154/discussion-between-will-and-zarko).

Answer (score 1):

If you allow linebreaks inside of the column headers you don't need to rotate them:

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newsavebox\mysavebox
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Results}
    \label{tab:tb1}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X *{9}{S[table-format=2.3]} }
      \toprule
      {\thead[l]{Name}} 
        & {\thead[l]{Category}} 
            & {\thead{Size\tnote{1}}} 
                & {\thead{No. of\\vertices}} 
                    & {\thead{No. of\\edges}} 
                        & {\thead{std. dev}} 
                            & {\thead{Avg.\\degree}} 
                                & {\thead{Avg.\\diameter}} 
                                    & {\thead{Avg.\\time 1\tnote{2}}} 
                                        & {\thead{Avg.\\time 2}} 
                                            & {\thead{Avg.\\time 3}} \\
          \midrule
I-SB0-SWR0  & {---} & 9.670 & 6.383 & 4.587  & 9.896  & {---}  & {---} & {---} & {---} & {---} \\
II-SB4-SWR0 & 4 Steel Bars \O{} \SI{6}{\mm}
                    & 15.80 & 9.966 & 5.10   & 15.451 & 56.133 & {---} & {---} & {---} & {---} \\
III-SB0-SWR4 & 4 P-SWRs \O{} \SI{3}{\mm}
                    & 14.650 & 9.369 & 5.338 & 14.525 & 46.776 & {---} & {---} & {---} & {---}\\
IV-SB2-SWR2 & 2 Steel Bars \O{} \SI{6}{\mm} and 2 P-SWRs \O{} \SI{3}{\mm}
                    & 15.240 & 9.680 & 5.748 & 15.0   & 51.576 & {---} & {---} & {---} & {---}\\
V-SB0-SWR8 & 8 P-SWRs \O{} \SI{3}{\mm}
                    & 19.490 & 12.050& 7.720 & 18.682 & 88.783 & {---} & {---} & {---} & {---}\\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \begin{tablenotes}
          \item[1] In MB
          \item[2] In ms
        \end{tablenotes}
      \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

---

More horizontal space around column 3:

[image]

```
\documentclass[8pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newsavebox\mysavebox
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \sisetup{table-format=2.3}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Results}
    \label{tab:tb1}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X @{\hspace{4\tabcolsep} }S @{\hspace{4\tabcolsep}} S*{8}{S}}
      \toprule
      {\thead[l]{Name}} 
        & {\thead[l]{Category}} 
            & {\thead{Size\tnote{1}}} 
                & {\thead{No. of\\vertices}} 
                    & {\thead{No. of\\edges}} 
                        & {\thead{std. dev}} 
                            & {\thead{Avg.\\degree}} 
                                & {\thead{Avg.\\diameter}} 
                                    & {\thead{Avg.\\time 1\tnote{2}}} 
                                        & {\thead{Avg.\\time 2}} 
                                            & {\thead{Avg.\\time 3}} \\
          \midrule
I-SB0-SWR0  & {---} & 9.670 & 6.383 & 4.587  & 9.896  & {---}  & {---} & {---} & {---} & {---} \\
II-SB4-SWR0 & 4 Steel Bars \O{} \SI{6}{\mm}
                    & 15.80 & 9.966 & 5.10   & 15.451 & 56.133 & {---} & {---} & {---} & {---} \\
III-SB0-SWR4 & 4 P-SWRs \O{} \SI{3}{\mm}
                    & 14.650 & 9.369 & 5.338 & 14.525 & 46.776 & {---} & {---} & {---} & {---}\\
IV-SB2-SWR2 & 2 Steel Bars \O{} \SI{6}{\mm} and 2 P-SWRs \O{} \SI{3}{\mm}
                    & 15.240 & 9.680 & 5.748 & 15.0   & 51.576 & {---} & {---} & {---} & {---}\\
V-SB0-SWR8 & 8 P-SWRs \O{} \SI{3}{\mm}
                    & 19.490 & 12.050& 7.720 & 18.682 & 88.783 & {---} & {---} & {---} & {---}\\
          \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \begin{tablenotes}
          \item[1] In MB
          \item[2] In ms
        \end{tablenotes}
      \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I want to have more space between specific columns (e.g. for col 2 and 3 and 3 with 4); how can I do that?

Comment: @Will: I have updated my question according.y You can of course adapt the value of `\hspace`according to your needs.